# How to find the next closest input outside of parent and parents in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I'm trying to update the value of the closest `input` to an element based on some conditions.

This doesn't seem to work at all.

To explain this better, here's a working example:

```js
$('.t').append('<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div><div class="block block-strong myBlock"><div class="imgHolder"><div data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?42344444444" class="addedImg"><div class="deletImg" data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?42344444444">X</div><img class="tappableImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" ></div></div></div><div><input type="text" class="input" value="22,44,66,99,ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?42344444444"/><div><div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div><div class="block block-strong myBlock"><div class="imgHolder"><div data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?423423" class="addedImg"><div class="deletImg" data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?423423">X</div><img class="tappableImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" ></div></div></div><div><input type="text" class="input" value="22,44,66,99,ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?423423"/>');

$(document).on('click', '.deletImg', function() {
  var $this = (this);
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var inp = $($this).parents().parent().eq(1).find(".input").val();
  inp = inp.replace(id + ',', '');
  inp = inp.replace(id, '');  //$($this).parents().parents().parent().eq(1).find(".input").val(inp);
});
```

```css
.addedImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.imgHolder {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: auto;
}

.myBlock {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.addedImg img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.deletImg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">

</div>
```

If you run the jsfiddle above, and click on the FIRST delete button (black X), it finds the `data-id` of that element and then it should look into the CLOSEST input for that `value/data-id` and update that input value only.

But at the moment, when I click on the delete button, it updates all the inputs!

Can someone please advice oaths issue?

Comment: Please post the [mcve] here, not at jsfiddle. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the question I answered a few hours ago?

Comment: @Barmar, it sort of is and isn't. The idea is the same BUT try to have multiple inputs and see if your example works.

Comment: In jQuery and JavaScript, "closest" means the closest enclosing ancestor, it doesn't mean nearby in other directions.

Comment: You're not using my solution from the previous question.

Comment: `.parents().parent()` makes no sense. It's the same as just `.parents()`

Comment: @Barmar, tested your version too and it doesn't work! there: https://jsfiddle.net/fnqakmp6/5/

Comment: I think you're missing a `</div>` in your fiddle. The second DIV is inside the first DIV.

Comment: Why are we arguing over what is in a fiddle?  If it isn't in the question proper, it isn't useful.  The code needs to be in the question.  See [mre].  Edit the code into the question.

Comment: @Barmar, with `parents()` I get nothing. at least with `parents().parent()` I get some value back!

Comment: That's not possible. `parents()` returns all the ancestors. Adding `.parent()` returns each ancestor's direct parent. So it's just all the ancestors except the direct parent of `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a typo in the HTML that you're appending to `.t`. The `<div>` after the `<input>` should be `</div>`.

The `input` is not contained in any parent unique to just the delete button. If you go up to the `.myBlock` DIV, you need to go to the next DIV after that and find the `.input` within it.

```js
$('.t').append('<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div><div class="block block-strong myBlock"><div class="imgHolder"><div data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?42344444444" class="addedImg"><div class="deletImg" data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?42344444444">X</div><img class="tappableImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" ></div></div></div><div><input type="text" class="input" value="22,44,66,99,ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?42344444444"/></div><div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div><div class="block block-strong myBlock"><div class="imgHolder"><div data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?423423" class="addedImg"><div class="deletImg" data-id="ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?423423">X</div><img class="tappableImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png" ></div></div></div><div><input type="text" class="input" value="22,44,66,99,ASAS-HHH-UUU-TEY.jpg?423423"/></div>');

$(document).on('click', '.deletImg', function() {
  var $this = (this);
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var inp = $($this).closest(".myBlock").next().find(".input").val();
  inp = inp.replace(id + ',', '');
  inp = inp.replace(id, '');
  $($this).closest(".myBlock").next().find(".input").val(inp);
});
```

```css
.addedImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.imgHolder {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: auto;
}

.myBlock {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.addedImg img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.deletImg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t">

</div>
```